# Is it possible to disable UITableview multiple 'cellForRowAt' method call when scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know UITableView 'cellForRowAt' method call every time when UITableViewCell visible. But my question is now, what is it possible to disable multiple call cellForRowAt method?

Comment: Why do you want that? If you get unexpected behavior on scrolling then you did something wrong, not the framework.

Comment: No and you shouldn't want to.

Comment: If you don't want that you can use UIScrollView

Comment: Of course I can use UIScrollView but it is time wasting for me to customize. I need complex home page design with infinity scroll. I wanted to use UIStackView but I don't find any UIStackView infinity scrollview library.

Comment: WoW! I encountered this issue inccidently. I never though that someone else have found this behavoir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Most probably no, because its called automatically by the tableview
  class.
- You can add up your own conditions to show or hide some rows.